# Omitting spread array from object

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a function:

```
const mergedPartOfStateWithCurrentSearchValues = (object, valuesToOmit) => {
  const {...valuesToOmit, ...rest } = object;
  return rest;
};
```

The first argument is an object. The second argument is an array of string values to omit from the object. I'm trying to return the rest. So this actually doesn't work like that. I've tried to use lodash as well:

```
const mergedPartOfStateWithCurrentSearchValues = (object, valuesToOmit) => {
  const filteredObject = pickBy(object, function (value, key) {
    return !valuesToOmit.includes(key)
  })
  return filteredObject;
};
```

And it doesn't work as well. I'm running out of ideas. How can I do what I want to and keeping the generic nature of this function?

Comment: do you have an example of `object` and `valuesToOmit`?

Comment: Let's say for example `object` is {a: 1, b: 2, c:3} and `valuesToOmit` is ['a','c'] so I want to return {b: 2}

Comment: Lodash has an `_.omit()` function that is doing exactly what you want. There is a caveat - omit is going to be removed in the next major version of lodash (5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reduce the array and get only an object without wanted keys.

It works by removing a single key from the object in each loop by using a [computed property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) and [assigning to new variable name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names) underscore, which is not used anymore and [rest in object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Rest_in_Object_Destructuring).

As result you get an object with without unwanted keys.

```js
const
    subSet = (object, without) =>
        without.reduce((o, k) => ({ [k]: _, ...o } = o, o), object);

console.log(subSet({ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }, ['a', 'c']));
```

Comment: No idea what is going on here but it's really elegant. Thx :)

Answer (score 3):

You could take the entries of your object using [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and then filter out the entries which keys appear in your `valuesToOmit` array by using the [`.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) and [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) methods. Then, you can use [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to build an object from these filtered entries:

```js
const object = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};
const valuesToOmit = ['a', 'c']

const mergedPartOfStateWithCurrentSearchValues = (object, valuesToOmit) => {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(object).filter(([k]) => !valuesToOmit.includes(k))
  );
}

const res = mergedPartOfStateWithCurrentSearchValues(object, valuesToOmit);
console.log(res);
```

If you [can't support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries#Browser_compatibility) `Object.fromEntries()`, you could map the entries returned by `Object.entries()` to objects, and then merge them into a larger object using [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```js
const object = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};
const valuesToOmit = ['a', 'c']

const mergedPartOfStateWithCurrentSearchValues = (object, valuesToOmit) => {
  return Object.assign(
    ...Object.entries(object).filter(([k]) => !valuesToOmit.includes(k)).map(([k, v]) => ({[k]: v}))
  );
}

const res = mergedPartOfStateWithCurrentSearchValues(object, valuesToOmit);
console.log(res);
```

**Note**: You can improve the efficiency of the above method by making `valuesToOmit` an ES6 [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), and then using the `.has()` method rather than the `.includes()` method.